# system.out.printl замена?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день!
Есть вопрос. Информацию сложно искать, так как с терминами слабо. Поэтому решил написать сюда.
Вот в большинстве примеров всё выводится через `System.out.printl`.
А есть ли возможность передать значение `System.out.printl` и вывести, например через Toast в андроиде.

Comment: Уточните про какие примеры вы говорите, насколько я знаю `printl` функция java которая выводит в консоль ответ. Переменную можно куда угодно передавать, вам нужно только выбрать способ вывода.

Comment: Кажется, вам нужен [`System.setOut(PrintStream out)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut-java.io.PrintStream-)?

Comment: да, вроде то что надо. спасибо

Comment: Будьте аккуратнее с этим методом на андроид девайсах, так как на разных устройствах может быть разное поведение, но обычно инфа выводиться в логи